# Are these two notations equivalent?

Tags: notation

I've seen both $\forall a,b$ and $\forall a\forall b$ of these being used in various posts and wondered if they are equivalent or if there is a subtle difference between the two.

Comment: They are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are the same.

Technically, the notation $\forall a \, \forall b$ is what one is supposed to write, but $\forall a,b$ is a shorthand usually used in lectures, notes, proof scratch work, etc. But you should definitely remember that $\forall a \forall b$ is the correct choice.

I have also seen some professors write $\forall a \ni \forall b$ where $\ni$ means "such that," and I have also seen (and personally use) $\forall a : \forall b$ where $:$ also means "such that."